# Trouble adding coupons and dynamic updating of totals to WooCommerce Mini-Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

UPDATE: This gets me closer, but the applying a coupon takes me to the cart page instead of updating within the mini-cart.

```
<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
        <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                        <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                            <div class="coupon">
                                <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>

    <div class="cart-collaterals">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' ); ?>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to add the coupon functionality to the mini-cart.php template and running into issues. If I copy the core coupon functionality from cart.php, nothing happens when I apply a coupon. The expected behavior is for the coupon to apply and the total updated (all within the mini-cart). Here's my mini-cart.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Mini-cart
 *
 * Contains the markup for the mini-cart, used by the cart widget.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.3.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart' ); ?>

<?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?>

    <div class="mini-cart-header">
        <div>Your Cart</div>
        <i class="icon-close mini-cart-close"></i>
    </div>

    <ul class="woocommerce-mini-cart cart_list product_list_widget <?php echo esc_attr( $args['list_class'] ); ?>">
        <?php
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart_contents' );

            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                    $product_name      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $thumbnail         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                    <li class="woocommerce-mini-cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'mini_cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                        <?php if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) : ?>
                            <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . '<div class="product-name">' . $product_name . '</div>' . '<div class="product-price"' . $product_price . '</div>' ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>" class="product-info">
                                <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . '<div><div class="product-name">' . $product_name . '</div>' . '<div class="product-price"' . $product_price . '</div></div>' ?>
                            </a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); ?>

                        <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                            '<a href="%s" class="remove remove_from_cart_button" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-cart_item_key="%s" data-product_sku="%s"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>',
                            esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                            __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                            esc_attr( $product_id ),
                            esc_attr( $cart_item_key ),
                            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                        ), $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
            }

            do_action( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_contents' );
        ?>
    </ul>

    <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__total total"><strong><?php _e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></p>

    <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
        <div class="coupon">
            <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <input type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons() as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
        <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $code ) ); ?>">
            <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon, false ) ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__total total"><strong><?php esc_attr_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' ); ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__buttons buttons"><?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_buttons' ); ?></p>

    <div>Related Products/Upsell</div>

<?php else : ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-mini-cart__empty-message"><?php _e( 'No products in the cart.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_mini_cart' ); ?>
```

Comment: Do you find anything?